# How to confirm file upload on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Uploading image in our ReactJS Website automatically uploads after the progress bar reaches 100%. We expected that it will confirm its upload once the user hits the post button. But the uploading feature is working well, but not in the expected. I am using FileUploader from react-firebase-file-uploader. how can I do the expected behavior?

```
class Announcement extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
    }


    state = {
        username: '',
        avatar: '',
        title: '',
        text: '',
        isUploading: false,
        progress: 0,
        avatarURL: '',
        images: null,
        urlStoreL: ''
    };

    handleUploadStart = () => this.setState({isUploading: true, progress: 0});
    handleProgress = (progress) => this.setState({progress});
    handleUploadError = (error) => {
        this.setState({isUploading: false});
        console.error(error);
    }



    handleUploadSuccess = (filename) => {
        const sessionId = new Date().getTime()
        this.setState({avatar: filename, progress: 100, isUploading: false});
        const storeReference = (downloadURL, sessionId) => {
            let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser
            // let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images').child('filename');

            firebase.database().ref('announceIMG')
                .push({
                    type: 'image',
                    url: downloadURL,
                    postTitle: this.state.title,
                    text: this.state.text,
                    createdAt: sessionId,
                    user: {
                        id: currentUser.uid,
                        email: currentUser.email
                    }
                })
        }



        firebase.storage().ref('images').child(this.state.avatar).getDownloadURL().then(url =>
            storeReference(url,sessionId)
        )

    };

    openModal() {
        this.setState({
            visible : true
        });
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({
            visible : false
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { open } = this.state;

        return (
          <div className="MainContainer">
              {/*<ModalComp/>*/}
              <div className="headingStyle" >
                  <h2 style={h2_style}>Announcements</h2>

                  <form action="" style={uploadComponent}>
                      <section>
                          {/*<h1>React-Modal Examples</h1>*/}
                          <input type="button" style={createAnnouncement_btn} value="Create an Announcement" onClick={() => this.openModal()} />
                          <Modal visible={this.state.visible} width="370" height="400" effect="fadeInUp" onClickAway={() => this.closeModal()}>
                              <div>
                                  <h1>Title</h1>
                                  <p>Some Contents</p>
                                  <label style={{marginLeft: "35px"}}>
                                    Announcement Title:
                                    <input type="text" style={mainDivInput} onChange={event => this.setState({ title: event.target.value })}/>
                                  </label>
                                  <br/>
                                  <label style={{marginLeft: "35px"}}>
                                      Write something about your announcement:
                                      <textarea style={mainDivTextArea} resize="none" onresize="none" onChange={event => this.setState({ text: event.target.value })} />
                                  </label>
                                  <br/>
                                  <br/>
                                  {this.state.isUploading &&
                                  <p>Progress: {this.state.progress}</p>
                                  }
                                  {this.state.avatarURL }
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label style={{backgroundColor: 'grey', color: 'white', padding: 5, borderRadius: '10', pointer: 'cursor', marginLeft: '22px'}}>
                                      Add Image
                                      <FileUploader
                                          hidden
                                          accept="image/*"
                                          storageRef={firebase.storage().ref('images')}
                                          onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}
                                          onUploadError={this.handleUploadError}
                                          onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}
                                          onProgress={this.handleProgress}
                                      />
                                  </label>

                                  <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{height: '40px', marginTop: '-75px', marginLeft: '205px'}} onClick={this.handleUploadSuccess} >Post</button>&nbsp;<button  type="cancel" className="btn btn-danger" style={{height: '40px', marginTop: '-75px'}} onClick={() => this.closeModal()}>Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                          </Modal>
                      </section>
                  </form>
              </div>
              <div className="FieldsContainer" style={container_style}>

              </div>

              {/*<form action="" style={uploadComponent}>*/}

                  {/*{this.state.isUploading &&*/}
                  {/*<p>Progress: {this.state.progress}</p>*/}
                  {/*}*/}
                  {/*/!*{this.state.avatarURL &&*!/*/}
                  {/*/!*<img src={this.state.avatarURL} />*!/*/}
                  {/*/!*}*!/*/}
                  {/*<label style={{backgroundColor: 'steelblue', color: 'white', padding: 10, borderRadius: 4, pointer: 'cursor'}}>*/}
                      {/*Upload Image*/}
                      {/*<FileUploader*/}
                          {/*hidden*/}
                          {/*accept="image/*"*/}
                          {/*storageRef={firebase.storage().ref('images')}*/}
                          {/*onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}*/}
                          {/*onUploadError={this.handleUploadError}*/}
                          {/*onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}*/}
                          {/*onProgress={this.handleProgress}*/}
                      {/*/>*/}
                  {/*</label>*/}


              {/*</form>*/}
                    <Feeds/>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Announcement;
```

Comment: "But the uploading feature is working well, but not in the expected." What is not working about it?

Comment: Also note that you shared quite a lot of code, which takes time for us to read. If you can reproduce the same problem with less code, it'll take less time for us to read, so it'll increase the chance that somebody will be able to help.